# Symfony framework - check database entry existence

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine-inheritance

Using symfony framework, which code is best to query database table to check if entry is already there?

I need query like this:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('t')
    ->where('t.email = ?', $email)
    ->andWhere('t.type = ?','newsletter');
```

Comment: What is `$this`? If you're using concrete inheritance you don't need to where on `type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easist way, assuming you're in a Doctrine_Table instance, which it appears you are is:

```
$this->findOneByEmail($email);
```

You shouldn't need `type` if you're using concrete inheritance because it will be added via DQL callback (assuming you have them enabled), but for completeness:

```
$this->findOneByEmailAndType($email, 'newsletter');
```

These will return the Doctrine_Record if it exists or null if it doesn't.

You can also use a count on your query:

```
$exists = $this->createQuery('t')
    ->where('t.email = ?', $email)
    ->andWhere('t.type = ?','newsletter') // your probably don't need this
    ->count();
```

This will return either the number of records that match the query. This a more efficient as it does not hydrate the results.

Comment: No problem, I keep an eye out for symfony/doctrine questions so keep them coming :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You can directly defined in form class.

---

```
$this->validatorSchema['email'] = new sfValidatorAnd(array(
    new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true, 'trim' => true)),
    new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model'=>'User','column'=>'email'),
    array('invalid' =>'Email Address already exist')),                   
    new sfValidatorRegex(
    array('pattern' => '~^(\s)*[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})(\s)*$~i'), 
    array('invalid' => 'Please enter valid email ID'))),
    array(),
    array('required' =>'Please enter email ID')
);
```

I think its much easier then other.